# How do I rebuild a table after adding a primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, primary-key, rdbms

I wanted to add a primary key to an existing table. I think that the best way to do this would be to do a `SELECT INTO` into a temp table, drop and create the table, and then `INSERT INTO` the created table from the temp table. Are there any issues that could arise from this?

Is this the best practice?

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

--SAVE DATA
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM dbo.OldTable AS tt

-- Drop and Create dbo.OldTable

-- Restore data
INSERT INTO dbo.OldTable (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT
    tt.Column1,
    tt.Column2,
    tt.Column3
FROM #TempTable AS tt

COMMIT TRANSACTION -- roll back in case there are any FK issues
```

This database is implemented in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Does it support auto increment keys?

Comment: I assume you mean a DB-generated PK?  E.g. a mysql autoincrement or a pgsql serial (or the like)?  If so, then I think the temp table is the easiest way to go if it's practical for your datasize.

Comment: This is in SQL Server 2008

Comment: if it supports sequence like Oracle or PostgreSQL it could be done in place assuming the database isn't in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new table as desired.
2. Insert into new table.
3. Drop old table.
4. Rename new one.

Comment: Is there any reason why this method would be safer or preferred over using a temp table?

Comment: One Insert instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to recreate the table. Use this script:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (KeyColumn1,KeyColumn2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add the PK "onsite" because this will save you both processing time and log space used.

So just do the following:

```
alter table dbo.OldTable add constraint PK_OldTable primary key (xxx)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!